# GCC 11 (arm-none-eabi) fails to find file which GCC 10 does find

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm, embedded

I have an assembler file `CyBootAsmGnu.s` which includes another assembler file `cyfittergnu.inc`:

```
.syntax unified
.text
.thumb
.include "cyfittergnu.inc"
// more
```

This file compiles fine with arm GCC 10, exact version:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10-2020-q4-major) 10.2.1 20201103 (release)
```

But fails with a newer GCC 11:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gcc -I/path/to/files -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -ffunction-sections -ffat-lto-objects -o CyBootAsmGnu.s.obj -c /path/to/files/CyBootAsmGnu.s
/path/to/files/CyBootAsmGnu.s: Assembler messages:
/path/to/files/CyBootAsmGnu.s:18: Error: can't open cyfittergnu.inc for reading: No such file or directory
```

The file is however exactly where it should be (which is also evident from the fact that GCC 10 can find and read it):

```
$ stat /path/to/files/cyfittergnu.inc
  File: /path/to/files/cyfittergnu.inc
  Size: 40788           Blocks: 80         IO Block: 512    regular file
Device: 2eh/46d Inode: 17169973579448684  Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2022-07-18 13:38:43.067197800 +0200
Modify: 2022-03-24 20:11:25.451266500 +0100
Change: 2022-03-24 20:11:25.451266500 +0100
Birth: -
```

Also note that both files (the including and the included) are in the same directory.

Newer GCC version reports as

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Toolchain for the Arm Architecture 11.2-2022.02 (arm-11.14)) 11.2.1 20220111
```

**Any idea why this is happening? Is something in the include search order changed between those compiler versions?** Should I open a bug report?

Operating system is Linux (NixOS) running an a WSL2 on Windows 10, however the same effect has also been seen directly on Windows 10 (on a different machine, and with a checked out copy of the repository on a different filesystem)

---

Compiling the file from within the directory `/path/to/files` works with both compiler versions. Also the path to the `-I` flag is definitively correct, the commandline is generated by CMake and the exact same command line arguments (and working directory and so on) are used with both compilers.

Comment: Run `strace -f -e trace=open` and see what locations both versions are searching.  The embedded chain has patches applied that may not be in the main gcc tree (another difference between v10 and v11 compilers).  You may have to get the command line of the sub-process that GCC spawns to invoke the assembler; the options might differ.  The '-I' option, should be `-Wa,-I` as this is an assembler include and not a C include.